# ¿Tengo un error de tags que no encuentro?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

El siguiente HTML es de prueba y no puedo hacer funcionar el JavaScript. Es para capitalizar la primer letra de cada palabra en un INPUT TEXT y si hay mayúsculas en el medio de una palabra las hace minúsculas. El ejemplo que vi online funciona, pero a mi no, ¿será la versión de jquery?. ¿O algún TAG mal?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="../jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//Leva a mayúsculas la primera letra de cada palabra
function titleCase(texto) {
    const re = /(^|[^A-Za-zÁÉÍÓÚÜÑáéíóúüñ])(?:([a-záéíóúüñ])|([A-ZÁÉÍÓÚÜÑ]))|([A-ZÁÉÍÓÚÜÑ]+)/gu;
    return texto.replace(re,
        (m, caracterPrevio, minuscInicial, mayuscInicial, mayuscIntermedias) => {
            const locale = ['es', 'gl', 'ca', 'pt', 'en'];
            //Son letras mayúsculas en el medio de la palabra
            // => llevar a minúsculas.
            if (mayuscIntermedias)
                return mayuscIntermedias.toLocaleLowerCase(locale);
            //Es la letra inicial de la palabra
            // => dejar el caracter previo como está.
            // => si la primera letra es minúscula, capitalizar
            //    sino, dejar como está.
            return caracterPrevio
                 + (minuscInicial ? minuscInicial.toLocaleUpperCase(locale) : mayuscInicial);
        }
    );
}

document.getElementById('ingreso')
    .addEventListener('input',
        event => {
            document.getElementById('ingreso')
                .value = titleCase(event.target.value);
        }
    );
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text"
       id="ingreso"
       placeholder="Escribí texto para llevar a mayúsculas la primera letra de cada palabra"
       style="width:100%">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que cuando buscas el id `ingreso` aun no ha sido definido en el documento.  Puedes solucionarlo utilizando la funcion `ready()` de jquery asi:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="../jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//Leva a mayúsculas la primera letra de cada palabra
function titleCase(texto) {
    const re = /(^|[^A-Za-zÁÉÍÓÚÜÑáéíóúüñ])(?:([a-záéíóúüñ])|([A-ZÁÉÍÓÚÜÑ]))|([A-ZÁÉÍÓÚÜÑ]+)/gu;
    return texto.replace(re,
        (m, caracterPrevio, minuscInicial, mayuscInicial, mayuscIntermedias) => {
            const locale = ['es', 'gl', 'ca', 'pt', 'en'];
            //Son letras mayúsculas en el medio de la palabra
            // => llevar a minúsculas.
            if (mayuscIntermedias)
                return mayuscIntermedias.toLocaleLowerCase(locale);
            //Es la letra inicial de la palabra
            // => dejar el caracter previo como está.
            // => si la primera letra es minúscula, capitalizar
            //    sino, dejar como está.
            return caracterPrevio
                 + (minuscInicial ? minuscInicial.toLocaleUpperCase(locale) : mayuscInicial);
        }
    );
}
$(document).ready(function(){
  document.getElementById('ingreso')
    .addEventListener('input',
        event => {
            document.getElementById('ingreso')
                .value = titleCase(event.target.value);
        }
    );
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text"
       id="ingreso"
       placeholder="Escribí texto para llevar a mayúsculas la primera letra de cada palabra"
       style="width:100%">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ahora funcionó perfecto, gracias!